# iOS: How to skip the push notification without being displayed when using notification service extension?

Tags: ios, push-notification, voip, ios13, unnotificationserviceextension

I am using Notification service extension to receive chat messages via push. Previously I was using VOIP to deliver chat messages. But with the new update from iOS 13 to restrict the usage of VOIP, I moved to Silent Push. But I could't handle the silent push when app is in terminated state.

So I have moved to Notification service extension. Everything is going good except the mute chat functionality. I want to receive push but it should not be shown, if the chat is muted. I know in Notification service extension, we can't skip it. But anyhow WhatsApp is doing exactly what I am seeking for.. I don't know how.

Is there any way to handle mute chat functionality from iOS 13 even in terminated state?????

Comment: WhatApp are most likely preventing push notifications for muted chats from ever being sent (i.e. they must have some logic on the server-side to trigger notifications only for non-muted chats)